# SAS Studio: Using data in "myfolders"

Tags: sas, virtualbox

everyone.

I have established a shared folder with VM Virtualbox and uploaded a .sas7bdat data file. When I open SAS Studio to use the university edition, I can see this data file in "myfolders." However, when I try to print the contents or do anything with this data file, I constantly get errors.

Below is my current code to move this data file into my work library.

```
PROC IMPORT DATAFILE="/folders/myfolders/Lawrence.sas7bdat"
OUT=WORK.lawrence;
run;
```

Then, I get this error:

```
1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
72         
73         *data Lawrence;
74         *run;
75         
76         PROC IMPORT DATAFILE="/folders/myfolders/Lawrence.sas7bdat"
77         OUT=WORK.lawrence;
ERROR: Unable to determine datasource type.  Please use the DBMS= option.
```

What is the "option" to use for a .sas7bdat data file?

I just want to manipulate this data file. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't import a SAS7bdat file, it's already in a SAS format. You can assign a libname and access the file directly.

```
libname myfiles '/folders/myfolders/';

proc print data=myFiles.Lawrence;
run;
```

Video tutorials are here: video.sas.com
Specific to this question: https://video.sas.com/detail/videos/sas-analytics-u/video/4664335810001/accessing-your-existing-data-in-sas-university-edition:-download-version?autoStart=true

Comment: Awesome, this was a simple solution. Thank you, Reeza!